# I'm searching cutting points of a central angle of a circle

Tags: geometry

I'm working in a 2D drawing software and I need to draw points of the  central angle cutting the circumference.

I have a circumference, I know how its center point (2D coordinates), I know the radius, and I know the angle at the center.

But I need to know (in 2D coordinates) which are the exact points where this angle cuts the circumference.

Thanks you so much.

Comment: Unless you have assumed the positive x-axis as the initial line of reference, otherwise there will be infinitely many points satisfying your given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the angle and the radius: think of the radius *r* as the length of the hypotenuse *h* of a triangle and use trigonometry to solve for the lengths of the x and y co-ordinates.

[image: Circle with Triangle in it.]

$\cos(\theta) = \frac{a}{h}$
rearrange to get
$a = h\cos(\theta)$
So length *OB* in the diagram will the same as length *a* in the equation above. So the co-ordinates of point *B* in the diagram are $$(h\cos(\theta), 0)$$
Using more trigonometry we find that the co-ordinates of point *A* in the diagram are $$(h\cos(\theta),h\sin(\theta))$$

Comment: I understand your drawing. Now, I  have all angles, the lenght of the hypotenuse and the lenght of the triangle's other two sides. If my coordeantes of circunference center are (x=4, y=5) for example,  i dont know how calculate coordeantes of  point  A in you drawing. 
Thanks you so much for your answer.

Comment: @JuanAntonio Are you saying that the circle center is at co-ordinates (4,5)? That detail should have been included in the original question. Can you just add 4 to the x co-ordinate and 5 to the y co-ordinate?  So point A would be at co-ordinates $(hcos(\theta) + 4, hsin(\theta) + 5)$.

Comment: Finally I've got that I wanted, thanks you so much for all help.

Answer (score 0):

From one corner and an arm as radial  reference find/plot the start reference point $ (R ,0). $ Next find other point using coordinates $ (R \cos A, R \sin A) $ using trig and mark it. Finished.